# Redis cluster on Docker Compose with network_mode host - Unable to connect to redis-cluster

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, redis, redis-cluster

I set up a **Redis** cluster with 6 nodes as follows. From the [redis-cluster documentation](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial), `network_mode` `host` must be used.

```yaml
version: "3.9"
    services:
        redis0:
          build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./DockerFile_Builders/Redis/Dockerfile-base
            args:
              PORT_CONFIG: 7000
              PORT_BUS_CONFIG: 8100
          network_mode: "host"
    
        redis1:
          build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./DockerFile_Builders/Redis/Dockerfile-base
            args:
              PORT_CONFIG: 7001
              PORT_BUS_CONFIG: 8101
          network_mode: "host"
    
        redis2:
          build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./DockerFile_Builders/Redis/Dockerfile-base
            args:
              PORT_CONFIG: 7002
              PORT_BUS_CONFIG: 8102
          network_mode: "host"
    
        redis3:
          build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./DockerFile_Builders/Redis/Dockerfile-base
            args:
              PORT_CONFIG: 7003
              PORT_BUS_CONFIG: 8103
          network_mode: "host"
    
        redis4:
          build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./DockerFile_Builders/Redis/Dockerfile-base
            args:
              PORT_CONFIG: 7004
              PORT_BUS_CONFIG: 8104
          network_mode: "host"
    
        redis5:
          build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./DockerFile_Builders/Redis/Dockerfile-base
            args:
              PORT_CONFIG: 7005
              PORT_BUS_CONFIG: 8105
          network_mode: "host"
    
    
        redis-cluster:
          tty: true
          build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./DockerFile_Builders/Redis/Dockerfile
          #hostname: redis-server
          depends_on:
            - redis1
            - redis2
            - redis3
            - redis4
            - redis5
          network_mode: "host"
        
        user_service:
          depends_on:
            - "redis-cluster"
          links:
            - "redis-cluster"
          build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: DockerFile_Builders/Services/User/Dockerfile
```

Now it is required to connect to the Redis cluster from the `user-service` container, when I try to connect using:

```java
RedisURI masterURI = RedisURI.create("redis://redis-cluster:7001");
```

I get the following error:

> 19:57:28.329 [lettuce-epollEventLoop-4-1] WARN  com.lambdaworks.redis.cluster.topology.ClusterTopologyRefresh - Unable to connect to redis-cluster/:7003
> chat_service_1          | java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.net.UnknownHostException: redis-cluster

However, when the `user-service` is launched locally (without the docker container) and the Redis cluster is still in a Docker container, the connection is established normally using:

```java
RedisURI masterURI = RedisURI.create("redis://localhost:7001");
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not a **Java** developer but it looks like you are building the DSN to your **Redis** cluster using the **Docker Compose** *service name*:

```
redis://redis-cluster:7001
```

> `redis-cluster` is the name of the service in your **docker-compose.yml** file

**Docker** provides such *hostnames* within its own networks from its [embedded DNS server](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#dns-services). As you are using the [host network mode](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/) there is no **Docker network** which are usually declared in the [`networks` section of the **docker-compose.yml**](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#network-configuration-reference).

That means that you must use host names known to your current machine. During development you can continue to use `localhost`. When deploying, depending on the architecture of your application I think you will have to use private/public IPv4 address of the production server.

> Managing multiple environments is easy with **Docker Compose/Swarm** using [multiple configuration files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/).